# ios 8 multipeer connectivity error on updateChat

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, multipeer-connectivity

http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/09/multipeer-connectivity-on-ios-8-with-swift.html

I have been following this tutorial to create a group chat, but I am running into this error.
Cannot invoke 'updateChat' with an argument list of type '(NSData, fromPeer: MCPeerID!)'

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
self.updateChat(msg as String, fromPeer: peerID!)
```